# How to get value of selected records in post function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I have a table of record that shows activities done by users

I also have check box associated with each record through which user can select more than one activity at a time

i want the id's of those record whose check box is selected by user

I can display multiple records but can not get value in my controller's post function

here is my code

```
  public ActionResult DisplayList()
    {
     //do activities to fetch record from database
 return View(modelList);//modelList is a viewmodel's Icollection list
    }
```

view:-

```
       @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
      @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
      <div style=" width:900px; height:400px;">
<div class="textcontent"><b>List of activities</b></div>

<div class="table" style="vertical-align:middle;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell" style="width:auto;">SrNo</div>
        <div class="cell" style="width:auto;">Select Activity</div>
        <div class="cell" style="width:auto;">Learner Name</div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i + 1 }))
    {

    <div class="row1">

        <div class="cell" style="width:auto;">@item.Index</div>
        <div class="cell" style="width:auto;"> <input type="checkbox" name="chkexi" id="selected" onclick="checked()"/></div>
        <div class="cell" style="width:auto;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.persn.FirstName)</div>

    </div>    
    }
</div>
     <div class="table">
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="cell">
            <center>
               <button type="submit">Submit</button>//on click of this my controller function is called 
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
 <script>
    function checked() {
if (document.getElementById('selected').checked) {
    document.getElementById('chkstatus') = true;
}
 </script>

     }
```

My View model:::

```
  public class PublishViewModule
{
    public virtual myclass obj { get; set; }
           public virtual bool chkstatus { get; set; }
}
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayList(ExhibitionViewModel model,FormCollection form)
    {
        //here i get model as null
        return View();
    }
```

can somebody help me with this

Comment: Could you post the form from your view, please

Comment: @Forty-Two: I added the code...bt in controller i'm getting "model" as null

Comment: please show your viewmodel class

Answer (score 0):

In your postback action, replace

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayList(ExhibitionViewModel model,FormCollection form)
```

with whatever better suits your needs:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayList(ExhibitionViewModel model)
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayList(FormCollection form)
```

or do some custom binding based on what you looking for. But those two are most obvious postback actions to use.

Here is the theory behind it: [ASP.NET MVC – Think Before You Bind](http://www.codethinked.com/ASPNET-MVC-Think-Before-You-Bind)

**Edit**

Couple things paid attention to:

1. Your view doesn't have any model at the very top so not sure if it even suppose to post it back, maybe this is why its null?
2. Try to look into this: your view model class called `PublishViewModule`, but you accepting `ExhibitionViewModele` in your post back action in the controller. Is that the problem?

Hope this helps

Comment: :wen i use public ActionResult DisplayList(ExhibitionViewModel model)i get model as null

Comment: @priya77 Just edited my answer, paid attention to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got answer....:)

I once again posted the question and i tried to pass those values through ajax
 here is the answer

[how to accept value passed through ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002930/how-to-accept-value-passed-through-ajax/12003045#12003045)

:)